# Neyman-Pearson lemma: critical region and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, gamma-distribution, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d r.v's with common p.d.f.
>
> $$
> \mbox f(x)=\frac{x^5e^{-x/\theta}}{5!\theta^6}
> $$
>
> where $\theta$ > 0. Show that the Neyman-Pearson lemma produces a test of $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ against $H_1: \theta=\theta_1 (\theta_1>\theta_0)$ with critical region of the form $\sum^n_{i=1}x_i≥c$ where $i=1,2,...n,x_i$ is the observation on $X_i$ and $c$ is some constant.
>
> Use the result "if $X_i$ are i.i.d with $X_i\sim Ga(\alpha,\beta)$, then $\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\sim Ga(n\alpha,\beta)$" to identify the distribution of $\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$. Hence find the equation which must be solved to find $c$.

My attempt:

$$
\frac{L(\theta_0)}{L(\theta_1)} =\frac{\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i^5e^{-x_i/\theta_0}}{5!\theta_0^6}}{\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i^5e^{-x_i/\theta_1}}{5!\theta_1^6}}
$$
Which I think simplifies to:
$$
=\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{e^{-x_i/\theta_0}\theta_1^6}{e^{-x_i/\theta_1}\theta_0^6}
$$

$$
=(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})^{6n}e^{-\sum x_i(\frac{1}{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{\theta_1})} 
$$

$$
=(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})^{6n}e^{-\sum x_i(\frac{1}{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{\theta_1})} 
$$

$$
(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})^{6n}e^{-\sum x_i(\frac{1}{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{\theta_1})} <c
$$

Edit: attempted continuation assuming I'm right (which is a dangerous assumption)

$$
6n log(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})-\sum x_i(\frac{1}{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{\theta_1}) <c
$$

$$
\sum x_i > \frac{6n log(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})-c}{\frac{1}{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{\theta_1}}
$$

$$
\sum x_i > c'
$$

Comment: taking logs of a product turns that product into a sum.

Comment: Routine bookwork questions are treated a little differently on the site. Please read the `self-study` [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and add the tag. You do show your attempt, and where you got stuck, so you may not need to edit your question further. Hopefully Eric's suggestion allows you to proceed. If you think you have a good answer, you should post it (as an answer to your question). You might consider using $g(\mathbf{x})=e^{\log(g(\mathbf{x}))}$ when making use of his suggestion.

Comment: Is this right?

$$
=(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0})^{6n}\frac{e^{-\sum x_i/\theta_0}}{e^{-\sum x_i/\theta_1}}
$$

Comment: your expression in logs at the end of your post is wrong (it's s simple error). If you fix it, you may find your progress easier.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: I've tried to go further too, although I'm probably wrong