# How to formulate a likelihood ratio test for an exponential distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, self-study, likelihood-ratio

> Find the form of the likelihood ratio test of $H_0 : \lambda = \lambda_0$ against $\lambda\neq\lambda_0$ when $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from $Ex(\lambda)$. Simplify it as much as possible.

I've started as follows, where $\lambda_1$ is some alternative parameter

$$
\frac{L_0}{L_1}=\frac{\prod f(x;\lambda_0)}{\prod f(x;\lambda_1)}
$$

I think the p.d.f. for an exponential is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ so

$$
\frac{L_0}{L_1}=\frac{\prod \lambda_0 e^{-\lambda_0 x_i}}{\prod \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x_i}}
$$

$$
=(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1})^n\frac{\prod e^{-\lambda_0 x_i}}{\prod e^{-\lambda_1 x_i}}
$$

Which I think can be simplified like this by taking logs

$$
=n log(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1})\frac{e^{-\sum\lambda_0 x_i}}{e^{-\sum\lambda_1 x_i}}
$$

Not sure about this but, I think that becomes

$$
=n log(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}) e^{-\sum x_i ({\lambda_0}-{\lambda_1})}
$$

Am I right so far? Not sure where to go from here. I think the critical region is where the above is less than some constant.

Comment: You forgot to log $(\frac{\lambda_{0}}{\lambda_{1}})^{n}$

Comment: You're correct that you'd reject the null for sufficiently small values, since that would indicate the likelihood for the null was unusually low if the null were actually true, indicating the ratio is smaller than it would be expected to ordinarily be. Can you write a rejection rule and manipulate it - pull constants out, transform, etc), so you're only dealing with a comparison of some simple statistic, $T(\mathbf{x})$ with some other constant, say, where $T$ will have some known distribution?

Comment: Not entirely sure what I'm doing but:

$$
n log(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}) e^{-\sum x_i ({\lambda_0}-{\lambda_1})}<c
$$

$$
log(n log(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1})) -\sum x_i ({\lambda_0}-{\lambda_1})<c'
$$

$$
\sum x_i>\frac {log(n log(\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}))-c'}{\lambda_0-\lambda_1)}
$$

$$
\sum x_i>c''
$$

Something like that?

Comment: someone mentioned that I might need to find the MLE to use as $L_1$, is that right?!

Comment: Although this seems a little different, the issue is *identical* to that expressed in your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99099: you need to review the properties of logarithms, as suggested in a comment there.

Comment: I've tried to do it in the other question again. Am I doing it right?